# grabadora de audio para Android

Tags: java, android

Hola muy buenas tardes!!
Soy una chica que está empezando en esto de la programación de android studio y la verdad que estoy un poco perdida y me he quedado estancada. Estoy trabajando en una grabadora. En esta tengo un botón para empezar y parar la grabación, cuando empieza a grabar todo va muy bien pero cuando le vuelvo a dar al botón para que acabe la grabación se me cierra directamente la aplicación diciendo que ha habido un error. He intentado mucha cosas pero la verdad que no lo llego a conseguir. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceré muchísimo. Ya que estoy en un proyecto muy importante para mi

```
package com.example.ejemplos;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaRecorder grabacion;
    private String archivoSalida=null;
    private Button btn_recorder;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_recorder=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_rec);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1000);
        }

    }
    public void  Recorder(View view){

        if (grabacion==null){
            archivoSalida =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Grabacion.mp3";
            grabacion=new MediaRecorder();
            grabacion.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            grabacion.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            grabacion.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            grabacion.setOutputFile(archivoSalida);

            try {
                grabacion.prepare();
                grabacion.start();
            }catch (IOException e){
            }

            btn_recorder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recr);
            Toast.makeText(this, "GRABANDO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (grabacion!=null){
            grabacion.stop();
            grabacion.release();
            grabacion=null;
            btn_recorder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recb);
            Toast.makeText(this, "GRABACIÓN FINALIZADA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }



    }
    public void reproducir (View view){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try{
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(archivoSalida);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

        }catch (IOException e){

        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "REPRODUCIENDO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }



}
```

En manifest tengo puesto los 2 permisos

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: [Captura de audio mediante la clase MediaRecorder](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/androidya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=158&inicio=20)

Comment: Que error te da ? puedes mostrarlo para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Es importante agregar cual es el mensaje de error mostrado en el LogCat,saludos.